# how to play background music in android cocos2d

Tags: android, cocos2d-android, simpleaudioengine

Hi i am new in cocos2d android. I couldn't find SimpleAudioEngine and CDAudioEngine in android cocos2d that is in iphone cocos2d. Then how can i play background music in android.

Answer (score 3):

hi here the code which i use try this is the way where you can use sound engine in four override methods hope it will help full for u

```
 @Override
 protected void onStart() {
// Preload background music
SoundEngine.sharedEngine().preloadSound(context, R.raw.theme_ver1);
SoundEngine.sharedEngine().playSound(context, R.raw.theme_ver1, true);
            SoundEngine.sharedEngine().preloadEffect(CCDirector.sharedDirector().getActivity(), R.raw.object_tap2);
            super.onStart();
        }

@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        SoundEngine.sharedEngine().pauseSound();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {     
        SoundEngine.sharedEngine().resumeSound();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        SoundEngine.sharedEngine().realesAllEffects();
        SoundEngine.sharedEngine().realesAllSounds();
        SoundEngine.purgeSharedEngine();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use SoundEngine (org.cocos2d.sound.SoundEngine).

Put your music file in res/raw folder and add the following code

```
SoundEngine.sharedEngine().playSound(context, R.raw.your_music, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

**I hope this will help you.**

```
Context context = CCDirector.sharedDirector().getActivity();
    SoundEngine.sharedEngine().preloadEffect(context, R.raw.pew_pew_lei);
    SoundEngine.sharedEngine().playSound(context, R.raw.background_music_aac, true);
```

**To stop the music**

```
SoundEngine.sharedEngine().realesAllSounds();
```